# Trouble with MySQLi and while loops

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code here within a class:

```
    function getRolePerms($role)
    {
        if (is_array($role))
        {
            $roleSQL = "SELECT * FROM `role_perms` WHERE `roleID` IN (" . implode(",",$role) . ") ORDER BY `ID` ASC";
        } else {
            $roleSQL = "SELECT * FROM `role_perms` WHERE `roleID` = " . floatval($role) . " ORDER BY `ID` ASC";
        }
        var_dump($roleSQL);
        $this->database->dbquery($roleSQL);
        $perms = array();
        while($row = $this->database->result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $pK = strtolower($this->getPermKeyFromID($row['permID']));
            var_dump($pK);
            if ($pK == '') { continue; }
            if ($row['value'] === '1') {
                $hP = true;
            } else {
                $hP = false;
            }
            $perms[$pK] = array('perm' => $pK,'inheritted' => true,'value' => $hP,'Name' => $this->getPermNameFromID($row['permID']),'ID' => $row['permID']);
        }
        return $perms;
    }
```

The var_dump() for $roleSQL is:

```
SELECT * FROM role_perms WHERE roleID = 1 ORDER BY ID ASC
```

and for $pK:

```
Admin
```

When running the query in the database directly i get a result with 8 rows.
Why is it that the loop does not recognize the multiple rows.
Also if i add the statement:

```
var_dump($this->database->result->fetch_assoc());
```

It dumps the array of the first row then the loop does the second row.

Im really baffled,

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol the answer actually lies outside the loop.

Calling this function `$this->getPermKeyFromID($row['permID'])` actually override the results from the database as it was using the same database object. I fixed it by storing the results in a separate variable local to that loop.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is this line here:

```
$perms[$pK] = array('perm' => $pK,'inheritted' => true,'value' => $hP,'Name' => $this->getPermNameFromID($row['permID']),'ID' => $row['permID']);
```

What happens is that all of the 8 rows you expect result in `$pK == 'Admin'`. When you do `$perms[$pK] = array(...)`, each one of the 8 loop iterations ends up writing to the same array key. In the end, there is only one value in the array.

If you change it to

```
$perms[] = array(...);
```

it should work as expected, because each iteration will add a new array element with a unique integer key.

**Side note:**

Avoid doing this:

```
$roleSQL = "SELECT * FROM `role_perms` WHERE `roleID` = " . floatval($role) ...
```

Since `roleID` surely is an integer, use the right tool for the job: `intval($role)`.

Comment: each value of $pK will be different. Also, there is the var_dump() within the loop, and in theory that should be executed 8 times, but it is not.

Comment: @FraserK: Then it's obvious that the error is something having to do with `$this->database->result`, which you don't give.

Comment: `$this->database->result` is a mysqli object. Like i stated above I can call `var_dump($this->database->result->fetch_assoc());` 8 times and it will dump the 8 rows. But the loop will not work like it should and i know the loop should work because this code `while($row = $database->result->fetch_assoc()){
 print_r($row);
}` works perfectly fine on another page. :)

Comment: @FraserK: Is there any chance the `continue` in there gets executed when it shouldn't be?

Comment: nah, i commented it out and it makes no difference